# Showing that $(x+1)$ is prime but not maximal in $\mathbb{C} [x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I'm trying to show that $(x+1)$ is prime but not maximal in $\mathbb{C} [x,y]$.

Is is not maximal because $(x+1)\subset (x)$. But why is it prime?
I know that it is enough to show:  x + 1 is prime, as element in $\mathbb{C} [x,y]$.

Thanks

Comment: You could also try to compute the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x+1)$ and show that it is an integral domain!

Comment: **Hint** $\ (x\!-\!a)$ is prime in $R[x]\iff R[x]/(x\!-\!a)\cong R\,$ is a domain. Put $\,R = \Bbb C[y],\ a = -1$

Comment: $(x+1)\subset (x)$ is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal $(x+1)$ is indeed not maximal, but it is false that $(x+1)\subset(x)$.
A maximal ideal containing it is, for instance, $(x+1,y)$.

A way to show that $(x+1)$ is prime is to observe that it is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism
$$
f:\Bbb C[x,y]\longrightarrow\Bbb C[y],\qquad f(P(x,y))=P(-1,y).
$$
Thus $(x+1)$ is prime because $\Bbb C[y]$ is a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint extracted from one of my old sci.math posts:

> Even  easier: the ideals $\rm\  (x\!+\!1)\ <\ (x\!+\!1,y)\ < 1\ $ are distinct primes$\  \ $  (or $1$)
>   since their residue rings $\rm\  \   C[y]\ \  >\ \ \ \ \ \ \Bbb C\ \ \  \ < \ \ \ 0\ $ are distinct domains (or $0$)